# How to read tensorflow checkpoints of old version?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used `tensorflow==0.11.0` to save my model. This uses the old format. My files are:

```
checkpoint_old/
    checkpoint
    DCGAN.model-9002
    DCGAN.model-9002.meta
```

How do I read the model using the `tensorflow==1.0.0`? The format for checkpoints has changed. This doesn't seem to work:

```
from tensorflow.core.protobuf import saver_pb2

saver = tf.train.Saver(write_version = saver_pb2.SaverDef.V1)
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state('checkpoint_old')
if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
    print ckpt.model_checkpoint_path #checkpoint_old/DCGAN.model-9002
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
```

Comment: any progess @canonball?